# which process is sending SIGKILL

Tags: linux, crash, signals, dbus, sigkill

In my linux system I have a daemon which starts very early ( during bootup ).
  The daemon during boot-up is just initializing the g_dbus name.
  Specifically :

```
        guint id = g_bus_own_name ( G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION,
                            DBUS_NAME,
                            G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_NONE,
                            bus_acquired_handler,
                            name_acquired_handler,
                            name_lost_handler,
                            NULL,
                            NULL);
```

But to my surprize I always get this :

```
        ##### deliver signal SIG : 9, [BT]<Process Name>#1(679) get_signal_to_deliver
        ##### deliver signal SIG : 9, [BT]<Process Name>#2(681) get_signal_to_deliver
```

I tried this as well :

```
        dmesg | grep -i 'killed process'
```

But the problem is , somehow, dmesg is empty. ( I think this has been done purposefully )

I have also checked the global & static variable in my process & there is no large memory which I am allocating. Further there is no memory leak as well

My Process also has root permission in the system so that is also not an issue.

Last point. after two or there automatic restarts from systemd ( of this daemon ) there is no problem at all.

Can some one help to understand this behavior? so that I am able to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
  Although, I am not an expert on the subject, here is how I solved & which given me the conclusion of what was happening.

First the solution, then we'll try to reason.

Check whether system bus is up or not:

```
          while(conn==NULL) {
             dbus_bus_get(DBUS_BUS_SYSTEM,&err);
             if(dbus_error_is_set(&err)){
                 usleep(1000*50);
              }
```

after that Just acquire the system bus :

```
    guint id = g_bus_own_name ( G_BUS_TYPE_SYSTEM,
                        DBUS_NAME,
                        G_BUS_NAME_OWNER_FLAGS_NONE,
                        bus_acquired_handler,
                        name_acquired_handler,
                        name_lost_handler,
                        NULL,
                        NULL);
```

Now there is no signal & the daemon works smoothly.

Now reason.
    I think, earlier I was trying to get the session bus, at the boot-up it was not created hence the kernel was sending signal 9 to my process. So, I moved to system bus, which is launched much early than session bus.
    Further, before even getting system bus, its pertinent to make sure even system_bus is up & hence the solution.

To answer which process is sending sigkill, it seems to me, there is no process in particular. It was coming form the kernel itself.

Hope this is useful to someone else as well.